# Oracle Materialized View in Entitiy Framework issue

Tags: oracle, view, edmx, materialized

I have the following issue.
 1. I created an Oracle Materialized View which contains the "WITH PRIMARY KEY" clause.
 2. when I am trying to add that View to my EDMX, I encounter the following error:
    "The table/view 'XXX' does not have a primary key defined and no valid primary key could 
    be inferred..."

Does anyone know how to add a primary key to Materialized View that can be added to EDMX?
Is this issue solvable ?

thanks,
Hagai

Comment: check ur table first. r u set PK or not?? u can set pk from sql plus or ODAC.

Answer (score 0):

This clause refers to the materialised view including a primary key column from the master table, not that it possesses a primary key itself.

A materialised view is simply metadata on a regular (base) table, so you can perform an alter table command using the name of the the materialised view to create a primary key on the base table.